# can i configure an apache VirtualHost Proxy BalancerMember as failover-only (e.g. hot/warm)?

Tags: apache-httpd, http-proxy, apache-virtualhost, load-balancing, reverse-proxy

i currently have a VirtualHost configured to load balance between 2 servers.  however, to avoid race conditions that occur when both instances are active, i would like to switch to a hot/warm configuration where the second server is only used when the first server goes down.  how can i configure that in my http.conf file?

here is my current VirtualHost config:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    ServerName redacted.example.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    <Proxy balancer://mycluster>
             BalancerMember http://10.0.0.1:8080
             BalancerMember http://10.0.0.2:8080
      </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster
    ProxyPassReverse / balancer://mycluster
</VirtualHost>
```

side notes: i would prefer to use apache httpd for this task, but i might consider other technologies if apache can't handle it. i am not sure i have the right terminology to describe a "alpha only if beta down" situation (e.g. hot/warm, failover, load balance)

Answer (score 0):

apparently, the terminology i'm looking for is "hot standby". here is the appropriate config (note the **status=+H**):

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    ServerName redacted.example.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    <Proxy balancer://mycluster>
             BalancerMember http://10.0.0.1:8080
             BalancerMember http://10.0.0.2:8080 status=+H
      </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster
    ProxyPassReverse / balancer://mycluster
</VirtualHost>
```

here is the relevant bit from [the documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass):

> status    -   Single letter value defining the initial status of this
>   worker. [...] H: Worker is in hot-standby
>   mode and will only be used if no other viable workers are available.